# Dynamic Javascript Object with multiple rows

Tags: javascript, performance, object, multidimensional-array

After searching for something similar here, it was not clear to me how to create an object with different levels of rows like the following example:

Example:

```
Object = { 1 : { name : bob , dinner : pizza }, 
           2 : { name : john , dinner : sushi }, 
           3 : { name : larry, dinner : hummus } 
         }
```

The idea is to create one withing a for loop since am extracting the info from a table it will be unknown as to how many rows it can have.

Then I would need to parse through the properties to check values. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: You'll want an array. Such as    var foo = {"arr" : [{ "name" : "bob" , "dinner" : "pizza" }, { "name" : "john" , "dinner" : "sushi" }]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward, really.

Start with an empty object:

```
var thing = {}
```

Make a loop that runs from 1 to the length of the table:

```
for(var ix=1; ix <= table.length; ix++)
```

Now for each `i` you can add a new object to your original object

```
for(var ix=1; ix <= table.length; ix++){
  thing[ix] = {} /* 1 */
}
```

You then need to replace the right hand side at 1 with something that fills in the object you want.

```
for(var ix=1; ix <= table.length; ix++){
  thing[ix] = { name: ..., }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this before and I have got "[object Object]" values.                 for(var t in thing ){
print(thing[t] );
}

Comment: @DavidHreben What's wrong with that? The value of each property is an object, as you desired.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what you'd get, because each item there is, you guessed it, an *object*.  Instead of print, try `console.log`, which expands the contents.

Comment: yeah, the thing is that I am using another system "Servicenow" and the logs shows the same "Object object" values. At least I know I was going the right direction. Thanks Martin!

Comment: Do you know how to use the developer tools?  If you can get to the console you can explore what that object is really like.

Comment: How would you get duplicates with the object structure you specified Martin?

Comment: Mmm, duplicates in what sense? That sort of code will give you a hash (object) with a different numeric tag for each row in the table. If those rows are duplicates , the the right hand side of the hash pair will have duplicate right hand sides.